# How to use ckeditor5 with Laravel

Tags: laravel, ckeditor5

I install ckeditor5 using npm after install them i put this code in app.js

```js
import DecoupledEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';
import PageBreak from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-page-break/src/pagebreak';

DecoupledEditor.builtinPlugins.push(PageBreak);
```

I include the `app.js` in my `blade` file and put this code in blade:

```html
<div class="document-editor__editable"></div>

<script>
    DecoupledEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('.document-editor__editable'), {
            plugins: [PageBreak],
            toolbar: ['pageBreak']
        })
        .then(editor => {
            console.error(editor);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
</script>
```

I got this error in console while running `npm run dev`

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6A4o.png)

Comment: It says the plugin is duplicated. Have you tried not adding the plugins: [PageBreak] line?